# From DMG to VirtualBox VM

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I have a partitions with older versions of OS X and I'd like to put the contents of the partition as a VirtualBox VM so I don't have to reboot in order to test my apps on previous versions. At the moment I turned the partition into a DMG, then using VBoxManaged I turned the DMG into a VDI. Then I created a new OS X Vm on VirtualBox and attached it to the vdi. I started the vm but it didn't boot correctly.

I read some articles on the internet about making an OS X Vm using VirtualBox and they all said you need a modified version of OS X in order for everything to work. Any ideas of what I have to modify in the DMG so I can successfully boot from the resulting VDI?